# Spring JPA save new Entity after checking if similar record exists

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I had implemented *addAnAuthor()* and **getAllAuthors()** methods in my author controller, my get implementation works just fine. However, if i try to add with a non-existing id i kept getting the below error in postman. Trying POST with an  existing **author id** overwrites the existing record and get a response code 201 created:

```
"message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
```

My add author implementation code is :

```
    public class AuthorService {
        @Autowired
        private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    public String addAuthor(Author author) {
            if(authorRepository.existsByFirstName(author.getFirstName())){
                System.out.println("checked exists");
                return "Already Exists";
            }

            else{
                authorRepository.save(author);
                return "Created";
            }


        }
}
```

Inside my repository i have this method:

```
boolean existsByFirstName(String firstName);
```

The author entity code is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String lastName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "author")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    protected Author() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you created autoincrement id with primary key in database